# confuse about the pointer, and its usage for c language programming

Tags: c, pointers

I have just learned how to use the point, and very confused about why we need to use it. let me bring up an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){

int a,b,*ptr;
a = 2;
ptr = &a;
*ptr = a;
b = *ptr // why not we assign the value of a to b directly (b = a;)
return (0);
}
```

above is one of example I saw on the video tutorial, I have not had any experience of using pointer. therefore I wonder why do we need it, can anyone show me the use of pointer? thank you

Comment: The assignment `*ptr = a` is the same as `a = a`. As for `b = *ptr` it's probably just for demonstration purposes. You really have to ask the author of the Youtube video.

Comment: You will understand it when you will use it. But it is useful as a function parameter. And even essential for passing arrays as function parameters.

Comment: This seems to be a poor tutorial video.

Comment: Consider that you have an array of a million "records" where each one is about one Mb, and you need to sort them in memory. How much time would shuffling those blocks around take? Now, if you could just "swap" pointers instead and use those for the "sorted order output"? Sometimes one asks the OS for a region of "heap memory" that is not known at compile time... Lots of use for pointers... They're one of C's most powerful (and fast!) offerings... (And wait 'til you delve into "pointers to functions"...)

Comment: This is because the given examples while teaching pointers are just garbage. They are not useful to teach the real purposes of a pointer but given only for showing hw to use pointers. The pointers are very handy when need to pass large amount of data between functions to process it. They serve as a holder of the start point of the large data. Imagine that you need to pass a 1024 byte large data to a function to process it. Because of the nature of  the CPUs it is impossible to do it. Pointers brings solution to this problem by just passing the first memory address of the data to the function.

Comment: Few keywords for you on use of pointers, function parameters; passing by value and passing by reference, arrays and passing arrays to functions, allocating large blocks of data, data structures; linked lists... Then there are function pointers. You can read about these topics, which can help you put the pointers in a context. However, the tutorial you use seems to be rather poor, I'd recommend getting a proper C book, at least in parallel with video tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

`"can anyone show me the use of pointer?"`

```
int main( int argc, char **argv ) ...
```

The 2nd parameter is a **pointer** to a (null terminated) array of **pointers** to `char` (recognised as being pointers to "null terminated strings".)

Conventionally, any C program's entry point is the function `main()` and most programs *receive* one or more parameters (as strings) when executed.

This is just one of many examples where you will encounter pointers in C source code.